# Scala type (inference) issue?

Tags: scala, types, jersey, inference

I'm developing a REST webservice in Scala using the [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) JAX-RS reference implementation and I'm getting a strange error.

I'm trying to create a [ContentDisposition](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/header/ContentDisposition.html) object using the [ContentDisposition.ContentDispositionBuilder](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/core/header/ContentDisposition.ContentDispositionBuilder.html).

`ContentDisposition.ContentDispositionBuilder` has two types `T extends ContentDisposition.ContentDispositionBuilder` and `V extends ContentDisposition`. The method `type` of `ContentDisposition` returns a builder instance.

The code

```
val contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build()
```

works however

```
val contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).fileName("dummy").build()
```

produces the compiler error

```
error: value build is not a member of ?0
val contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).fileName("dummy").build()
                                                                                                         ^
```

(Note that `type` needs to be put in "quotation marks" because it's a keyword in Scala)

`fileName` of `ContentDispositionBuilder` returns an instance of `T` so this should actually work.

I don't get this. Any idea?
I'm using Scala 2.9.0.1 by the way.

**Update:**

This works. But why do I need the casting here?

```
val contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  .fileName("dummy")
  .asInstanceOf[ContentDisposition.ContentDispositionBuilder[_,_]]
  .build()
```

Comment: Is it just me or none of your links seem to work?

Comment: It seems java.net is down at the moment :-(

Comment: The error has something to do with interop between Java wildcards and Scala existentials. Although similar, these two type system features are not the same. This is a shot in the dark, but it might be worth trying with the just released Scala 2.9.1.

Comment: I have had a few interop problems with 2.9.0.1 when using Hadoop (TextInputFormat does not work where an InputFormat is expected).  Things worked better with 2.9.1.  I would at least hope that you would get a more informative exception!

Comment: 2.9.1 didn't fix this problem for me :( I still have to use the explicit casts.

Comment: This is tangential, but you may want to check out scalatra as a Jersey alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I guess type inference can only go so far... You can probably do it in two lines, without having to do any casts; have you tried this?

```
val something=ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
val contentDisposition=something.fileName("dummy").build()
```

or maybe

```
val builder=ContentDisposition.`type`(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).fileName("dummy")
val contentDisposition=builder.build()
```