# Does the Scala WartRemover address the issues outlined Yang Zhang's critique?

Tags: scala

[Yang Zhang](https://twitter.com/yaaang) provides [the following critique](http://yz.mit.edu/wp/true-scala-complexity/) of the Scala language stating the following:

- Operating On Collections
- specialized types (see [specialized types vs. subtyping](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scala-user/specialized/scala-user/Hug8GbuIEzg/u9ISu6wycnMJ)),
- path-dependent types (see [Bakery of Doom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860163/what-are-some-compelling-use-cases-for-dependent-method-types) for cake-patterned dependency injection),
- [Java wildcards-Scala existentials interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253779/scala-type-inference-issue),
- [extractor object and partial function asymptotic complexity](http://code.technically.us/post/13107005975/or-else-its-rilly-complex),
- [delimited continuations vs. type inference](http://www.heisenbug.info/archives/9-Delimited-Continuations-vs.-For-Comprehensions.html),
- [traits vs. eager vals Shamanism](https://twitter.com/#!/djspiewak/status/147053700546969601),

The [Scala Wart Remover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) addresses the following issues:

- Any
- Any2StringAdd
- AsInstanceOf
- DefaultArguments
- EitherProjectionPartial
- IsInstanceOf
- ListOps
- NoNeedForMonad
- NonUnitStatements
- Nothing
- Null
- OptionPartial
- Product
- Return
- Serializable
- Unsafe
- Var

My question is: **Does the Scala WartRemover address the issues outlined Yang Zhang's critique?**

Comment: No. The critique and Wartremover seem to me to have entirely different aims and be talking about entirely different things.

Comment: Could you expand on that so I can fix the question @TheArchetypalPaul ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly not. Wartremover addresses a few of the "which of these lines doesn't compile" trivia questions, by making any code that follows particular bad forms an error. But that was (IMO) never the interesting part of that critique.

Implicit macros (in 2.11) and Shapeless 2.0 address the issue with extending a collection; Miles' 1-line-of-boilerplate-per-type solution is now a 0-line-of-boilerplate-per-type solution (it is achieved using a macro which you could argue is cheating, but you don't have to write the macro yourself, you can call a standard one in Shapeless). And as always we should emphasise that the complaint here is that it's hard to do in Scala what's impossible to do in any other language (except, like, Idris or something).

The community is still not great at responding to criticism, IMO. That said, Scala seems to be getting more and more successful in terms of solving real business problems; I get the feeling that use is growing on most fronts, which suggests that any complexity is either not the problem the critique claims, or at least possible to work around. Certainly at my current employer we're doing more Scala than ever before, and producing better, more maintainable programs, with less effort, as a result.